# Set custom error pages for ASP.GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to set a custom error page instead of the traditional one for my asp gridview connected to my database. For instance, when I try to delete an object that have some dependencies (foreign keys), I would like to display a userfriendly message for the user.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no place to catch the offending code then your best bet might be to use asp.net's custom error pages which will display a specific page whenever an unhandled exception occurs.  To enable custom errors add the following section to the web.config file

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error.aspx">
</customErrors>
```

For more on custom errors take a look at: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

In the custom error page add this code to the page load event to check what the last error was that occurred and  display a friendlier message:

```
Exception lastError = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError;
if (lastError is SqlClient.SqlException)  // Check that the last exception was a Sql Exception
{
    SqlClient.SqlException sqlex = (SqlClient.SqlException) lastError;
    switch (sqlex.Number) // Check what type of Sql error occurred
    {
        case 124:  // FOREIGN KEY Constraint failed referential check upon DELETE of row in referenced table
            // Display appropriate error message on the page
            break;
    }
}
```

For a more on the Sql error numbers go to http://www.scribd.com/doc/7679522/SQL-Server-Error-Codes

Answer (score 0):

I had just to set the CustomError mode="On" in my web.config and redirect to a custom error.aspx page